# Force browser to re-fetch data from server instead of browser-cache (for a cacheable page)

Tags: caching, browser

Current browsers keep cached data in order to save re-fetching data again from server. However there are situations when we need to tell browser to re-fetch data from server i.e. when a new production release has gone live.

Many people know of Crtl+F5 but most people don't generally use that because they don't even know that a new version of site has gone live.

One common method used is to append version number or timestamp at end of file e.g. http://host/jquery.js?v=2, http://host/jquery.js?v=3 etc. But this will only work when browser fetches the latest HTML where the version number is updated. If browser still fetches from cache, then it would load http://host/jquery.js?v=2 instead of http://host/jquery.js?v=3.

Is there a way to force browser to invalidate all cache and reload from server (whenever a user loads the page after a new version of site has gone live)?

Please note: Using 'no-cache' meta is not an option here as this will make the page non-cacheable.

Comment: you should look into response headers